# Is it possible to style Python GUI like you would style HTML with CSS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, styling

I work a lot with HTML & CSS for Web Development, and I've only recently transitioned to Python for software development. I've done some of the basics with Python, my proudest moment being I programmed a calculator through Python using the TKinter, but I'm going to be honest with you it's quite ugly. I know how to change the foreground and background color, but that's about it. I was sort of hoping there was a way to style Python like you would style HTML with CSS. Is something like this possible?

I don't know if this is too broad of a question, but I really just need some sort of answer. Even a link to some sort of YouTube video to get me down the right path would be nice. I would also like to learn how to do other GUI style's like transitions, hover effects, and keyframes, but that's for another question.

Comment: Dear Vincent, that's not possible.

Comment: Try [tkstylesheet](https://pypi.org/project/tkstylesheet/), it doesn't use CSS but a custom simple stylesheet language. You can read the [documentation](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkStyleSheet/blob/master/Documentation.md) and [examples](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkStyleSheet/tree/master/Examples).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside of python your options are quite less, but never none. You have options starting from `ttk` from `tkinter`, which uses your OS native widgets and with `ttkthemes` you can get more themes for `tkinter`. But if you are planning to go on for a more modern GUI, using HTML, CSS and JS, then you do have [`Eel`](https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel) for python. There is also a python wrapper for `Qt`, [`PyQt`](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) which also provides powerful GUI toolkit. And also [`Kivy`](https://kivy.org/) which can also give you some kind of modern looks. Using `tkinter` is mainly for simple projects and it has its own limitations. But one of the limitation is your imagination and designing skill, for example here is a GUI I made with `tkinter`:

[image]

It does not look top of the mark or anything, but it kind of looks better than the traditional looks you get out of the box.

Comment: +1 for _"But one of the limitation is your imagination and designing skill"_ I like to think of tkinter like a lumber and hardware store - very little completed furniture, but all of the raw materials you need to build almost whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

First off, Web Design with CSS is a lot prettier, in Python you have less options.

But there is an editor called `QT Designer`, it lets you create GUIs and use them in your C++ or Python script. You may give it a try.

Keith Galli made a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8-snVfekto) on a Python GUI with TKinter which doesn't look that bad, regarding it's made with Python.